# Convert list to list of dictionaries: Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following sample list.

```
my_list = [('User2', 'String'), ('User2', 'Integer'), ('User3', 'String')]
```

I would like to append `name` and `dtype` in the list and would like to get a list of dictionaries similar to as follows.

```
my_new_list = [{'name':'User2', 'dtype':'String'}, {'name': 'User2', 'dtype':'Integer'}, {'name': 'User3', 'dtype':'String'}]
```

Here how I try it:

```
my_new_list = [] 
for i in my_list:
    my_new_list.append(i['name'])
    my_new_list.append(i['dtype'])
```

Anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
my_list = [("User2", "String"), ("User2", "Integer"), ("User3", "String")]


my_new_list = [{"name": u, "dtype": s} for u, s in my_list]
print(my_new_list)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"name": "User2", "dtype": "String"},
    {"name": "User2", "dtype": "Integer"},
    {"name": "User3", "dtype": "String"},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```py
my_list = [('User2', 'String'), ('User2', 'Integer'), ('User3', 'String')]
my_new_list = []
for i in my_list:
    my_new_list.append({'name':i[0],'dtype':i[1]})
print(my_new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
test_list = ["John", 3, "Jack", 8, "Jane", 10]
key_list = ["name", "number"]
n = len(test_list)
res = []
for idx in range(0, n, 2):
    res.append({key_list[0]: test_list[idx], key_list[1] : test_list[idx + 1]})
print(str(res))
```